# Refresh rate flicker using Nvidia drivers > 358 in 16.x

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I've got a GTX-580 powering a newer 1920x1080 display and a fairly old LG at 1280x1024.

Using any driver lower than 358 both displays work fine. All the drivers after 358 cause the LG display to exhibit refresh rate flickering at its native resolution and refresh rate (60.02Hz). Any resolutions lower than this work as they should.

I've tried using both HDMI and DVI with the same result. `parse-edid` says the EDID is only partially read, but that's also the case for the working drivers; the monitor shows up as it should in the Nvidia settings and xrandr.

It's definitely a driver issue, I've tried various display managers with the same result. I've had no success changing any of the relevant Nvidia settings or using xrandr.

I tried adding custom modes in xrandr to see if setting the framerate to 59 or a flat 60 has any effect, but (presumably due to the display's EDID), I just get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

Same behaviour in both 16.04 & 16.10, although 16.10 won't work with drivers < 367 for me.

Any suggestions to overcome this?